# How to load and boot a physical installation of Ubuntu inside the RAM memory

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, ram

Is there a method /script to load / boot / convert a physical installation of Ubuntu and load everything inside the RAM memory of the PC ? I've already installed Ubuntu,I don't need to do this. I need to understand how to run it from the memory. And I also need to understand how to write the changes I do to the OS permanently on a SATA disk. Or,to explain this with different words : how to convert a physical installation of Ubuntu into a live system but adding the ability to save the changes I do inside the OS to fixed disk.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing and I think impossible. If it is running in memory how is a SATA disk involved?

Comment: I know that there are live disks that allows to save the changes to a disk using the persistence mode. Don't put a negative vote for this question. its not fair.

Comment: Who said I did? Also a persistence USB is not what you were describing.

Comment: Mkusb will create a persistent USB with the boot option `toram`. This will run everything inside the computers RAM. I understand that Ubuntu mainly runs in RAM anyway.

Comment: Do u have a tutorial to suggest ?

Comment: Tempted to -1 but won't this time: Too much arguing in the comments. And multiple questions (too broad) in a single Question.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291291/how-to-know-whether-xubuntu-is-running-on-ram-or-the-live-usb

Comment: And: https://askubuntu.com/a/1251782/43926